# @media only screen and (max-width: 545px) property not working

Tags: media-queries

This is my site.. http://debt-trust.co.uk/home my problem is that my media screen css not working at the max width 545px... bu it will effect if the max width of browser is in @490px is there any who can help with my problem. thanks

@media only screen and (max-width: 545px){

```
.main-navigation {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: #b5e61d;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 3px; 
}

#rightlogo{
width: 50%;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem there is an issue sometimes in the hosting sites that there is an error during for the updating there hosting site